# Adding values from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df1

```
    Date         Open         Expiry    Entry Strike
0   2020-01-03  12261.10    2020-01-09  12200.0
1   2020-01-10  12271.00    2020-01-16  12200.0
2   2020-01-17  12328.40    2020-01-23  12300.0
3   2020-01-24  12174.55    2020-01-30  12100.0
4   2020-01-31  12100.40    2020-02-06  12100.0
```

i want to add values from df2

```
    Date         Expiry    Type  Strike Price   Open    Close
0   2020-01-03  2020-01-09  CE     13100         0.0    65.85
1   2020-01-03  2020-01-09  CE     13150         0.0    59.40
2   2020-01-03  2020-01-09  CE     13200         0.0    53.55
3   2020-01-03  2020-01-09  CE     13250         0.0    48.15
4   2020-01-03  2020-01-09  CE     13300         0.0    43.25
```

i want to compare elements of column `Date , Expiry and Entry Price` with `Date ,Expiry and Strike Price` of df2 and add corresponding `Open` column element to df1 if the condition matches. when i directly compare columns i get errors like .

```
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

thanks for the help

Comment: can you share your code so we can see what has been done. also can you share expected results so we know what you are looking for please?

Comment: `df1["Entry CE"] = df2["Open"] if (df1['Date'] == df2['Date']) & (df1['Expiry'] == df2['Expiry'])& (df1['Entry Strike'] == df2['Strike Price']) else " "` i tried this . i dont know if its the correct way. i am new to pandas .

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to do a simple merge and see if it solves what you want.

Do something like this:

```
pd.merge(df1,df2,how='left', left_on=['Date','Expiry','Entry Strike'], right_on=['Date','Expiry','Strike Price'])
```

Your output will be as shown below. For this, I modified the first row to match. Otherwise, the data has no matching records.

```
         Date    Open_x      Expiry  ...  Strike Price Open_y  Close
0  2020-01-03  12261.10  2020-01-09  ...       12200.0    0.0  43.25
1  2020-01-10  12271.00  2020-01-16  ...           NaN    NaN    NaN
2  2020-01-17  12328.40  2020-01-23  ...           NaN    NaN    NaN
3  2020-01-24  12174.55  2020-01-30  ...           NaN    NaN    NaN
4  2020-01-31  12100.40  2020-02-06  ...           NaN    NaN    NaN
```

You can then delete all columns that you don't want.

Comment: wow.. it worked . thanks man . it worked so quick that i have doubt now and checking the output manually .

Answer (score 1):

You can try with apply function aswell

```
def check(row):
    dt = row['Date']
    ex = row["Expiry"]
    sp = row["Entry Strike"]
    return df2[(df2['Date']==dt) & (df2['Expiry']==ex) & (df2["Strike Price"]==sp)]['Open']

df1['new_col'] = df1.apply(lambda x:  check(x), axis = 1)
```

this will also work, check the output below I have changed one of the value to match one row.

```
df1

      Date      Open        Expiry   Entry Strike   new_col
0   2020-01-03  12261.10    2020-01-09  13100.0      0.0
1   2020-01-10  12271.00    2020-01-16  12200.0      NaN
2   2020-01-17  12328.40    2020-01-23  12300.0      NaN
3   2020-01-24  12174.55    2020-01-30  12100.0      NaN
4   2020-01-31  12100.40    2020-02-06  12100.0      NaN
```